# dataframe how pivot table based on substring of the column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-science, pivot-table, pandas-melt

I have a dataframe:

```
df = 
time id ser1 ser2 ... ser20 N0ch0 N1ch0 N2ch0 N0ch1 N1ch1 N2ch1 N0ch2 N1ch2 N2ch2 N0ch3 N1ch3 N2ch3
  1   2  4    5         3     8     7     8    5     1      4    6     2      7    9    8      6
```

And I want to pivot it based on the channel ('ch' substring), such that it will become a column, so new dataframe will be:

```
time id channel ser1 ser2 ... ser20 N0 N1 N2
  1   2   0      4    5         3   8  7  8
  1   2   1      4    5         3   5  1  4
  1   2   2      4    5         3   6  2  7
  1   2   3      4    5         3   9  8  6
```

What is the best way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) to save any columns which should be unmodified. Then [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) the remaining columns on 'ch' which appears to be the delimiter between new column name and channel number. Then [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) in order to go from MultiIndex columns to long form. Follow up with [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) to turn the new channel column into an int from a a string (if needed).

```
# columns to save
idx_cols = ['time', 'id', 'ser1', 'ser2']
res = df.set_index(idx_cols)
# Separate N value from channel number
res.columns = res.columns.str.split('ch', expand=True).rename([None, 'channel'])
# Go to long form
res = res.stack().reset_index()
# Convert to number from string
res['channel'] = res['channel'].astype(int)
```

`res`:

```
   time  id  ser1  ser2  channel  N0  N1  N2
0     1   2     4     5        0   8   7   8
1     1   2     4     5        1   5   1   4
```

---

Alternatively [`wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) can be used which abstracts some of the reshaping, but requires a follow up [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to get the channel number, and manually specifying all "stubnames":

```
# columns to save
idx_cols = ['time', 'id', 'ser1', 'ser2']
res = (
    pd.wide_to_long(
        df,
        i=idx_cols,
        j='channel',
        stubnames=['N0', 'N1', 'N2'],  # all stub names (add more if needed)
        suffix=r'ch\d+'  # suffix
    ).reset_index()
)
# Get only the channel numbers and convert to int
res['channel'] = res['channel'].str.extract(r'(\d+$)').astype(int)
```

`res`

```
   time  id  ser1  ser2  channel  N0  N1  N2
0     1   2     4     5        0   8   7   8
1     1   2     4     5        1   5   1   4
```

---

Note for either option `idx_cols` can be created dynamically instead of manually.

By slicing first `n` columns (4 for this sample code):

```
idx_cols = df.columns[:4]
```

Or by filtering the DataFrame columns based on condition (like [`str.startswith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html):

```
idx_cols = ['time', 'id', *df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('ser')]]
```

---

Sample Setup:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'time': [1], 'id': [2], 'ser1': [4], 'ser2': [5],
    'N0ch0': [8], 'N1ch0': [7], 'N2ch0': [8],
    'N0ch1': [5], 'N1ch1': [1], 'N2ch1': [4]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can start by using [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) with parameter `id_vars` set to your 'ser' like columns and 'time' + 'id'.

You can then split the 'variable' column into 2, where one of the columns will be used as an index column when using [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html), and the other will be a `column`:

```
# Columns to be used as index in melt & pivot
id_cols = ['time','id'] + list(df.filter(like='ser'))

# Melt and split a column
m = df.melt(id_vars = id_cols)
m[['N','channel']] = m.variable.str.split('ch', 1 ,expand=True)

# Pivot the melted dataframe
out = m.pivot_table(index = id_cols + ['channel'],  columns='N', values='value').reset_index()
```

prints:

```
   time  id channel  ser1  ser2  ser20  N0  N1  N2
0     1   2       0     4     5      3   8   7   8
1     1   2       1     4     5      3   5   1   4
2     1   2       2     4     5      3   6   2   7
3     1   2       3     4     5      3   9   8   6
```